# WooCommerce custom single page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to build out a custom view for single product pages within WooCommerce. If a product say lives in a category called 'custom' I want WooCommerce to detect this by switching to a custom page layout if the product lives in that category.

I have tried to do this by adding the following code to single-product.php

```
    if (is_product_category( 'custom')) {
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-custom' );
    } else {
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
    }
```

I have created a category called 'custom' and also created a template called 'conent-single-product-custom.php'but I get an error if I place an item in the custom category which is the following:

*Warning: include(/home/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/woocommerce/single-product-custom.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php on line 89*

Comment: I followed these instructions to accomplish that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75906/how-to-check-if-the-product-is-in-a-certain-category-on-a-single-product-php-in: